# Inactive drop down menus on Android when user-scalable=no

Tags: android, html

I'm having a problem with native drop down menus becoming inactive in the stock browser when I set

```
user-scalable = no
```

in the viewport meta tag.

As soon a I remove this specification the drop down menus are active again

This is happening on my Samsung Nexus S on v2.3.6 have been unable to test on other flavours of android!

Does anyone know a workaround where I can leave user-scalable set to no...?

Thanks